# When install bundle,failed to install sass?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When install bundle, error messages always displayed.
As when you execute the order of installing bundle every time,they will show you the one error info.
Now when installed sass,the error information is “  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://ruby.taobao.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sass-3.4.22.gemspec.rz)”.
I’m new here,so hope get everyone’s help.Thank you so much in advance…...

Comment: try running gem update --system before anything else

Comment: @Boltz0r Thank you so much,I will try….

Comment: @Boltz0r But the same error showed ….

Comment: i think it's your rubygems host thats wrong... give me a second

Comment: bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org

Comment: show me your gemfile please

Comment: Ok, @Boltz0r   Based on your advice solved it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont have the correct source for your gems: change:

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: Yeah perhaps that’s the root cause .How to learn it ?Give me some advice.

Comment: But How to change the mirror ,same error occurred  when installing sqlite3…@BoltzOr

Comment: in your gemfile you have a line saying source 'xxxxxxx' change it to source ' 'https://rubygems.org'

Comment: I tried this command line order.gem sources -remove https://ruby.taobao.org
The information is source emove not present in cache
bogon:blog zhaoxinqiang$ gem sources -a https://rubygems.org the information is “EPIPE: Broken pipe - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)"

Comment: @BoltzOr change the source of gem ,but it cannot work well.I set the source as you said,but it told me failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net:443 (Connection reset by peer - connect(2) for "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" port 443)…….

Comment: I cannot change gem file ,I tried to change it to [link](https://rubygems.org/).But failed @BoltzOr……

Comment: Post your gemfile into the question please

Comment: Ok,I will try @Boltz0r